# SignInManager.SignInPasswordAsync is not logging in the User in ApiController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an ApiController that handles ajax login requests. Below is what is happening in the code:

```
// I tried with HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get... and it didn't work either
private ApplicationUserManager userManager => Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationManager>();
private ApplicationSignInManager signInManager => Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginJson request)
{
    var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);
    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, request.Password, true, true);

    if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            throw new Exception("Why are you not authenticating!!!");
        }
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

That exception is always thrown (i.e. the result is `Success` and yet `IPrincipal` reports that user is not authenticated yet).

What is even weirder is that if I reload the page I am **taken to the dashboard page** (Dashboard is the default home page for authenticated users), meaning the previous request actually did log the user in. But then why would `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` return false in my first login request? Any ideas?

Note: this is only happening for `ApiController`, a normal MVC `Controller` logs the user in correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authentication cookie is only set when your controller send a reply to a client (browser). And `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is checking if the cookie is set. But you are trying to check if the cookie is set within the same request as where you set the cookie.

In other words you can only check if user is authenticated only on the following request after you call `PasswordSignInAsync`. So remove that `throw new Exception...` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @trailmax, however, the exact copy of the above code works fine in a standard `Controller`. Do you happen to know any behavioural difference of the `User` (`IPrincipal`) object in these two types of controllers?

Comment: That is strange that it works on MVC, it should not (never did for me anyway). In MVC5 API controllers are quite different from MVC controllers, I suspect there will be different behaviour in OWIN middleware when it is API. To be honest, I have not looked into OWIN-API interoperability.

Comment: Hey @trailmax, many thanks. I got curious after reading your comment and have a second look at my mvc controller, and realised I was redirecting user to another controller action in which I was doing the authentication check. It looks like the cookie has been set when it was doing the redirect. Thanks for helping me out! :)

Comment: @JoelMin Ah, cool! I almost started to doubt myself. Yes, cookie is set on redirect because it actually does send a 301-reply to the client and next request from the client will have the cookie set.